# Use Google Cloud Functions to speed up GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I have a GAE standard Python app that does some fairly computational processing. I need to complete the processing within the 60 second request time limit, and ideally I'd like to do it faster for a better user experience.

Splitting the work to multiple threads don't seem to be a good solution because the threads would likely run on the same CPU and thus wouldn't give a speed up.

I was wondering if Google Cloud Functions (GCF) could be used in a similar manner as threads.  For example, if I create a GCF to do the processing, split my work into 10 chunks, and make 10 GCF calls in parallel, can I expect to get results 10x faster?  (aside from latency and GCF startup costs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each function invocation runs in its own server instance, and a function will scale up to 1000 instances to handle concurrent requests in parallel.  So yes, you can do this, if you are willing to potentially pay the cold start cost of each server instance as it's allocated for its first request.

Comment: Looking at the [pricing page for GCF](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing-summary/), there doesn't seem to be a cold start cost.  Did you mean latency cost or price cost?

Comment: Yes, it's a time penalty, not a monetary penalty.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to split the workload in smaller chunks that you'd be launching in parallel via separate (external) requests I'd suspect you'd get a better performance (and cost) by using GAE itself (maybe in a separate service) instead of CFs:

- GAE standard environment [instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) can have higher CPU speeds - a B8 instance has 4.8 GHz, the max [CF CPU speed](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) is 2.4 GHz
- you have better control over the GAE scaling configuration and starting time penalties
- I suspect networking delays would be at least the same if not better on GAE - not going to another product infra (unsure though)
- GAE costs would likely be smaller since you pay per instance hours (regardless of how many requests the instance handles) not per request/invocations

Comment: Interesting idea, but GCF seems like a better solution for me.  With a service: (1) you pay for 15 minutes of it even if you use it for a minute, (2) to launch 10 instances of a service for 1 minute (to do it in parallel), I believe I'd pay for 2.5 hours, and (3) an additional service always costs money and I think my GCF usage would fall within the free quotas.

Comment: For the technical side, I suspect network delays and startup time would be similar enough for my use case. Since I'm trying to finish something in 60 seconds an extra half second in startup costs or network delay doesn't really matter.  The benefit of parallelism should let me finish in 10 seconds or so.

Comment: Note that I am not suggesting reworking your existing GAE service, I'm taking about a new service handling a request in exactly the same manner as your CF would.

Comment: Dan, yes, that was my understanding though I think my comments apply to that.